# Maps not loading after releasing on Play Store

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maps

I just released an app on the Google Play Store thats using Google Maps to show a map with some markers. When I try it on devices from Eclipse everything works but after I downloaded the app from the Store the map won't load, it's just a white screen with the + and - icon in the corner.

I would guess it has something to do with the API key.

I'm using SupportMapFragment and in my manifest I have this:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.x.x.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.x.x.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="*Signature here*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right KEY. You signed your apk with production key and you should use it to get your map key.
It could be you are still using a debug key.
It happend to me the same problem because i forgot to change the map key.

Comment: Thanks, I followed a tutorial that only explained how to get a debug key and it didn't say I needed a new one before releasing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two keys, release key and debug key. Debug key is normal one.and release key is what you have to create.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Release certificate finger print is given.